# PowerBI line chart growth from 100%

Tags: filter, powerbi, percentage, measure, linegraph

In PowerBI, I want to compare the value growth of categories (lets take A and B) over time from any starting year. To compare this easily, I am using a line graph with the time on the x-axis and category as a legend. I would like both categories to start at 100% and show the growth relative to that starting point. I then want to be able to use a continuous date slicer to vary the start and end-points of my line graph.

I've created a dummy data to illustrate this

```
Category, Year, Value
A 2000 5
A 2001 8
A 2002 8
A 2003 10
B 2000 10
B 2001 8
B 2002 12
B 2003 10
```

Without any date filter, I would like to display years 2000-2003 with the following values for the lines:

```
A: 100%, 160%, 160%, 200%
B: 100%,  80%, 120%, 100%
```

(The first value of category A is 5. Therefore the line graph should display A's values relative to 5. It's values 5, 8, 8, 10 are then displayed as the mentioned percentages. The first value of category B is 10, so B's values should be displayed relative to 10).

With a date slicer set to filter years 2001-2003, I want the line values to become:

```
A: 100%, 100%, 125%
B: 100%, 150%, 125%
```

(Due to the slicer the first value of category A is 8, so I want the % values relative to 8. The first value of B is also 8)

I was thinking of writing a measure for this. Can anyone help me with it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the logic of the calculation?

Comment: I want the lines to show the % compared tot he first(!) displayed year of that category. In the case of no date filter, the first year of A is 2000 with value 5. Therefore I want all values displayed relative to 5. Since A's values are 5, 8, 8, 10, the relative values become 100%, 160%, 160% and 200% Similar for category B, the year 2000 value is 10. So it's values should be displayed relative to 10. If I change the first visible day of my line chart by applying a slicer, then I want the percentages to change based on the newly first displayed year. That way each category always starts at 100%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a measure to establish the earliest filtered year, the value for that year, then divide each evaluated value by the min year value:

```
MyMeasure = 
VAR MinYear = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        MIN ( MyTable[Year] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( MyTable[Year] )
    )
VAR BaseValue = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( MyTable[Value] ),
        REMOVEFILTERS ( MyTable[Year] ),
        MyTable[Year] = MinYear
    )
VAR CurrentValue = 
    SUM ( MyTable[Value] )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( 
        CurrentValue,
        BaseValue
    )
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: This is a very cleanly written solution. Thank you!
Is there a reason why you used 'REMOVEFILTERS' for the 'BaseValue' and not 'ALLSELECTED'?

Comment: Performance. ALLSELECTED is complex, effectively removing all filters, and then reapplying the selected ones... using REMOVEFILTERS to simply remove all the filters is simpler and faster.